# Android Studio white Breadcrumbs

Tags: android, android-studio, breadcrumbs

I have no idea how this breadcrumbs appeared. I want to know how to remove it. Thanks.

Android Studio 3.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click above white bar > Breadcrumbs > Don't show.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on that Breadcrumbs and then choose `Don't show` option inside `Breadcrumbs`